# Section and template folder problem

Tags: sections

I hope anyone can help me to get started. I think I have a brain freeze or something.

I have created a section (structure) that is called "House".
I want this section to use a template. In craft/templates/ I have created the folder "house" with the file index.html in it. I have also tried _entry.html.

When I then go my URL (for example): project.com/house it can´t find anything. Could not find the path on the server.

Is there something "wrong" on the server that don't allow access to that URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever template path you decide to go with, make sure you set that in the section’s settings. So if it’s `house/_entry.html`, make sure you put `house/_entry` in your section settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Is it possible to put a test text in the _entry.html file to test if it loads? For example a simple <p> tag

Comment: @Joe Yeah, you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: I have tested the above with no result unfortunately. The requested URL can´t be found. I have a feeling that it is not looking in the craft/templates/house folder and trying of connecting to my public HTML folder instead.

Comment: @Joe If you contact us from your Craft Support dashboard widget (and make sure to send your templates & database backup), we can help look into this from there.

Comment: Thank you. When I changed the htaccess file to .htaccess it worked! Thank you all for the help in this issue.